Find the limit of an integral using Darboux/Riemann sums
In a calc 2 homework assignment, I was given the following exercise:
Calculate the limit (without using the Newton-Leibniz formula, since we were given this homework before learning the fundamental theorem of Calculus. So we're only allowed to use Darboux/Riemann sums, because that is what we learnt):
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 cos^nxdx$$
They also us a hint: given $\epsilon\in(0,1)$, split the integral into:
$$\int_0^{\epsilon} cos^nxdx + \int_{\epsilon}^{1} cos^nxdx$$
But I am not sure how this helps us.

Could it be that you have made a mistake with your limit value above? $\int_0^1\cos^n(x);\text dx$ is a real number that does not depend on $x$ but on $n$. Did you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}$?

Is n>0? Or n can be any real number?

@Konstruktor yes, I fixed it now. Thanks.

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad, n is a natural number > 0.

@natitati add that info in your post

Proceed further with the split. The first integral doesn't exceed $\epsilon$ as integrand doesn't exceed $1$. The second integral doesn't exceed $(1-\epsilon)\cos^n\epsilon$. Conclude that limit is $0$.

I am elaborating on Paramanand Singh's comment. For all $\varepsilon \in \left( 0, 1 \right)$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} {\cos}^{n} \left( x \right) \text {d} x
& = \int_{0}^{\varepsilon} {\cos}^{n} \left( x \right) \text {d} x + \int_{\varepsilon}^{1} {\cos}^{n} \left( x \right) \text {d} x \\
& < \int_{0}^{\varepsilon} {1}^{n} \, \text {d} x + \int_{\varepsilon}^{1} {\cos}^{n} \left( \varepsilon \right) \text {d} x = \varepsilon + \left( 1 - \varepsilon \right) {\cos}^{n} \left( \varepsilon \right).
\end{align}
$$
Taking the limit of both sides yields
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} {\cos}^{n} \left( x \right) \text {d} x < \varepsilon + \left( 1 - \varepsilon \right) \cdot 0 = \varepsilon.
$$
Let $\varepsilon \to 0$.

@Gonçalo, I didn't know editing is possible without undeleting. I tried and yes, it works. Thanks for commenting!

And because it's true for every $\epsilon$ between $0$ and $1$, the limit must be $0$. I understand the idea, but what is the formal explanation for what I just said?

@natitati, the squeeze theorem. Is this what you are looking for?

@natitati: the theoretical justification of last step of taking limits comes from the concept of limit inferior and limit superior of a sequence. For the current case if $I_n$ is the sequence of integrals in question then $0\leq I_n\leq \epsilon +(1-\epsilon)\cos^n\epsilon$ where $\epsilon $ is a fixed but arbitrary number in $(0,1)$. Taking limits as $n\to\infty$ we get $0\leq \liminf I_n\leq \limsup I_n\leq \epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary this forces us to have $\liminf I_n=\limsup I_n=0$ so that $\lim I_n=0$.

@natitati: On the other hand you may avoid liminf and limsup because one knows that $I_n$ is decreasing as $n$ increases and the sequence is bounded below by $0$ so that $\lim I_n$ exists and then squeeze theorem works fine as indicated in the answer.

@Simon Yes! thats what I was missing. Thank you all!

\begin{align}
\color{#44f}{\int_{0}^{1}\cos^{n}\left(x\right){\rm d}x}
& =
\int_{0}^{1}\exp\left(n\ln\left(\cos\left(x\right)\right)\right)\,{\rm d}x \stackrel{{\rm as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\,{nx^{2} \over 2}\right)
{\rm d}x
\\[5mm] & =
\color{#44f}{\sqrt{\pi \over 2}{1 \over n^{1/2}}}
\end{align}

Just wow!!${}{}{}$

I don't understand your limit transition. How can the right-hand side still depend on $n$ after $n\to\infty$?

@Konstruktor expansion

Oh sorry, I had read the tilde as an arrow. You mean the asymptotics. Brilliant.

Thanks for your answer, but we didn't learn about integral with $\infty$ as one of the limits yet.

Maybe this solution won't be useful to the OP, but it will be useful to the other members of MSE.
Let $$A=\int_0^1\cos^n x \:\ dx$$
We can rewrite $A$ as
$$A=\int_0^1\cos^{2\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)-1} x \sin^{2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-1}x \:\ dx$$
$$\implies A=B\left(\frac{n+1}{2},\frac12\right)$$
Some simplification will yield
$$A=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)\sqrt{\pi}}{\frac{n}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}$$
Now $$\lim_{n\to\infty}A$$
will clearly be $\boxed{0}$ using Stirling's approximation.
